# HTML page inside Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My question is simple for some but difficult for others (like me).

I have a Shiny Dashboard in wich I want to add an html page inside a menuItem (Se connecter) to log in
[image]

Otherwise if you have any suggestions to do so using Shiny I'll be pleased

PS : I have a web service to log in so all I want is ideas to have a good looking, stylish login page or panel

Comment: have you looked into `iframe`?

Comment: What about http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp using e.g. `<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can `iframe` it into your dashboard?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Some Iframe"), 
                mainPanel(fluidRow(                    
                  tags$iframe(seamless="seamless",src="http://www.investing.com/quotes/streaming-forex-rates-%E2%80%93-majors", height=800, width=1400)
                )
                )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]