# Embedding a webpage with d3 into shiny

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny

Here is some interesting/ annoying behavior.  The below code is the "Hello world" of shiny apps (old faithful geyser), with only one addition in the UI:

```
includeHTML('https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e6f9e160585c153fa5ec543bd12b81e9')
```

)

I also split it into tabPanels for clarity.

That link above is to a standard D3 example on bl.ocks.org.  However when it renders in shiny, the d3 block simply renders as "Not Found".

Any idea how to get around this and embed a website with d3 into shiny?

Full reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
   tabsetPanel(
     tabPanel("main",
   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )),
   ## Illustrate that d3 does not render
   tabPanel("no_d3",
     includeHTML("https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e6f9e160585c153fa5ec543bd12b81e9")
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `tags$iframe` something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247438/5894457)